# std::mt19937 and std::uniform_real_distribution returning boundary value every time

Tags: c++, c++11, random

OK, so I've got some RNG code that (when all is said and done) boils down to this:

```
#include <limits>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

double randomValue() {
    // Seed a Mersenne Twister (good RNG) with the current system time
    std::mt19937 generator(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(
        std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(),
        std::numeric_limits<double>::max()
    );

    // Problem lives here
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        std::cout << dist(generator) << "\n";
}
```

The output from this is 30 lines of `inf`. Why?

Compiling with `g++` Debian 4.9.2-10, using `-std=c++11` and no other flags. And, before anyone else comments on it, I'm using the built-in Mersenne Twister-based RNG because my application requires high-quality random numbers, and seeding it with the system time (so no, it's not just the same seed over and over again).

Comment: Have you tried `srand(time(NULL))`? I've never used boost's random objects, but I was taught you always have to seed the rng.

Comment: That's what the arg to the RNG is doing - seeding it with the current system time. That said, I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Probably there is 'b - a' turning into 'inf' somwhere in the uniform_real_distribution. Check your std implementation.

Comment: Instead of `lowest()` and `max()`, have you tried just using `1.0` and `5.0` or something?

Comment: @Tas: That works correctly. But, for my applications, I need the full range of possible values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [C++14 section 26.5.8.2.2 paragraph 2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf#paragraph.26.5.8.2.2):

```
Requires: a ≤ b and b − a ≤ numeric_limits<RealType>::max().
```

In your case, b-a is greater than the allowed range.